# How to call mask() jquery function onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call jQuery function mask() onclick. The code I tried is below but it didn't work please help.

```
<input type="text" onclick="$('addAccountContactForm\\:homePhone').mask('(999)999-9999')" maxlength="13" value="" name="addAccountContactForm:homePhone"  id="addAccountContactForm:homePhone"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text" maxlength="13" value="" name="addAccountContactForm:homePhone" id="addAccountContactForm:homePhone" />
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('addAccountContactForm\\:homePhone').click(function() {
        $(this).mask('(999)999-9999');
    });
});
```

Comment: I cant use jquery is there any option without using it?

Comment: I didn't get you cant use jquery and you want to call a jquery function

Comment: I am working on JSF where the jquery script will be blocked and if i have to call javascript or jquery functions then i have to call it using events such as onclick and onchange.